# Home Network with 2 routers

Tags: networking

I am newbie regarding networking . . .

I have a Netgear router that points to my ISP and provides DHCP address to inside devices (pretty basic). I have connected a second D-Link router with "outward facing" interface static IP to match that of the internal IP range of the Netgear router. This second router provides a different set of IPs to any machines attached to it - basically trying to setup an isolated test lab. Machines connected to the 2nd router can see the "Internet" and browse/ping with no issue.

Machines connected to the first router cannot connect to either the second router or any machines on the second IP range . . .

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any responses.

---

Sorry I didn't provide enough info . . . [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIFKmJ4wufc) maybe not a good idea??

ISP Router: Netgear X4S R7800 (providing IP range 192.168.0.*).

"test lab" router: D-Link DIR-836L (providing IP range 192.168.2.*) with
"Internet" tab set to: IP - 192.168.0.200 (to connect to ISP router).

I'm a newbie at networking, so any info supplied is much appreciated.

Comment: I don’t know what you’re missing because I don’t know what you’re asking.  You say you are “basically trying to setup an isolated test lab” — it sounds like you have succeeded. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: first, you are double NATing from what i gather from your post. second, add the model numbers for both routers to the question. they may support RIP routing, if you need to keep the two sub-nets separate, you would disable the firewall on the second, and either setup a static route to the other, or enable RIP routing on both.

Answer (score -2):

You need to setup your routing table. Open up a command prompt and enter "route print", it will respond with your routing table. You need to edit this, so that packets intended for the second network are routed to the second router.
It's time to read up on routing tables.

Comment: This is incorrect. -1, why would you tell someone to edit the host routing table when the op has two routers? You would have to do this from every client device... 

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Are you sure it is incorrect? He has two (/24) subnets. Can a router automatically route packets from its own IP range to the other router's? A client with IP 192.168.0.x will able to access an another client, which is connected to 192.168.2.x/24 network, without static routing?

Comment: @dead candidate, yep that's exactly what routers are for. Both routers need a static or dynamic route to the others subnet. But even most home-grade routers are RIP capable.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart O.K., but RIP is working over the WAN? I have a very little experience with it: a router with openwrt connected to an Asus with stock fw. As far as I know, RIP was enabled everywhere I could enable it, but the outer Asus can't find route to the openwrt's LAN devices, until I've set static routing. (it could been PEBKAC, naturally)

Comment: openWRT had NAT/firewall off? I believe both dd-wrt and openwrt have it on by default. Try it again after an update, maybe it was just a firmware release bug. If it doesn't work, post it as a question. I'll try to help.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I've destroyed that net some years before, but thanks! ;) (I just tried to explain, why I've asked it)

Comment: Sorry all - I will not insult anymore